# How can I estimate the length of Proof of Work based on data size

Tags: math, blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

Can you estimate how long it should take to solve a proof of work puzzle based on the size of the data? For example if you have data of size 5 mb, you can estimate the suitable proof of work solving time to be  20 secs, 10 mb would be 50 secs, etc

Comment: Determine how many trials on average it takes to solve the puzzle, say N. Now benchmark how long it takes to do a much smaller number of trials, say K trials in S seconds. Then S/K is the number of seconds per trial, so N * (S/K) is an estimate of how long it takes on average to solve the proof of work puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of Work puzzle types similar to Bitcoin are independent of the data size. Informally, the puzzle is about trying different random values appended on a formed block, that when hashed, produce a digest that has a specific number of bits as a prefix pattern.

Formally, in Bitcoin, the puzzle is to find a random number *r* such that:

**H(b||r) < D**

where *b* is the block to be formed (including a set of picked transactions from the mempool) and *D* is the "difficulty" parameter, which changes dynamically over time in the network to keep the puzzle solving-rate as steady as possible. The "difficulty" of solving the puzzle is the same for a given hash function H (with specific digest size in bits) and the threshold D, no matter if the block size b is just 1KB or 1TB.

So the estimated time to solve the puzzle is eventually based on *D* and the number of hashes/second your system can do. In Bitcoin, this translates to brute-force a value for r. Note that there might be a case that no *r* for this puzzle exists, so in this case a different transaction set must be picked (i.e. change *b*).